# Copying a Websocket client / Listening to an existing Websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am really new to WebSocket and what I am trying to achieve is basically to listen as a client from an existing WebSocket connection, or duplicate a connexion to a server.

## A bit more context

On [this page](https://flusk-privacy-testing.bubbleapps.io/version-test), there is a Web Socket that is called "notify.bubble.is".

I would like to listen to the messages coming from the server (especially one that is `has-last-change-flusk-privacy...`) from a Node server.

[Existing Web Socket Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zb8n.png)

## The problem

I tried several things in order to listen to this WebSocket :

- Writing function 'onmessage' on the window.WebSocket object to log the message into the console (did not work)
- Creating a new WebSocket and connecting it to the same address as the existing one (wss://notify.bubble.is) but it receives no messages
- Overriding prototype of window.WebSocket object to rewriting the 'onmessage' function (did also not work)
- Adding an EventListener to the document with event 'onmessage' but it receives no messages

So I'm a bit confused...
I'm 99% sure there is a way to fetch these messages, and I think you guys could have wonderful and maybe out-of-the-box ideas (or maybe it's very easy and I'm just so bad)!

If you need more details, more info, or anything... just ask and I'll answer as soon as I can.
Thanks, guys! :)

Answer (score -1):

To listen to websockets in developper tools. Click here (based on your screen capture)
[image]

You the messages will appear there.

[image]